# Adding range to list using linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to populate a list of a custom class using the AddRange method.

Here is the custom class:

```
public class Hook
{

    public Hook(System.Data.DataRow values)
    {
        this.text = values[0].ToString();
        this.category = values[1].ToString();
        this.weather = values[2].ToString();
        this.timeofday = values[3].ToString();

    }

    public string text { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string[] associatedLandmarks { get; set; }

    public string weather { get; set; }
    public string timeofday { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my object array that I need to filter objects from, I am populating it using values from a datatable:

```
        int numberofhooks = result.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1;
        Hook[] Hooks = new Hook[numberofhooks];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofhooks; i++)
        {
            Hooks[i] = new Hook(result.Tables[1].Rows[i]);
        }
```

I need to filter out a subset of these objects using a variable that gets updated on the fly, which is a property of the class.

'category' is the property

I am using the AddRange method to do this, but it isn't working. What can be the issue with this? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

```
List<Hook> RelevantHooks = new List<Hook>();

        foreach (string category in relevantHookCategories)
        {
            RelevantHooks.AddRange(from item in Hooks
                                   where item.category == category
                                   select item);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"? What specifically is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: When debugging, what does `from item in Hooks
                                   where item.category == category
                                   select item` return?

Comment: This literally can not be answered until you tell us what isn't working.  Is there an error and if so what is it?  Or are the results not what you expected and if so please give the input, desired output, and the incorrect output that you are currently getting.

Comment: Apologies, the code is working, there are no errors. The problem is that RelevantHooks does not get populated using this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. If you want all the rows from your table why are you using:

   > int numberofhooks = result.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1;

   It should be:

   ```
   int numberOfHooks = result.Tables[1].Rows.Count;
   ```

   Perhaps the last item that you are excluding has the category you are looking for.

---

2. When you say "on the fly" I'm assuming that you want to have the subset `RelevantHooks` updated even after your query, when modifying `Hooks`, if that's the case then you don't have to use a List, just define your relevantHooks as:

   ```
   IEnumerable<Hook> relevantHooks = Hooks.Where(h => relevantHookCategories.Contains(h.category));
   ```

   e.g. If you modify the category property for any of `Hooks` items:

   ```
   Hooks[0].category="Other Category Value";
   ```

   Will either exclude or include the first hook from relevantHooks

Answer (score 0):

`RelevantHooks.AddRange(Hooks.Where(hook => category == hook.category));`

should be enough. You don't necessarily need the select clause in this case.

Comment: This should do the exact same thing as what the OP has.

Comment: but then again the code *should* be working right? There's a lot of *should's* here but i don't give up on *should*

Comment: The problem is that the OP hasn't told us what the issue is.  Maybe the code compiles and runs but they are not getting the results they want.  So rewriting the query format in method format wouldn't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use AddRange. Just iterate Hooks once and check if it's one of the categories.

```
RelevantHooks = Hooks.Where(h => relevantHookCategories.Contains(h.category)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RelevantHooks.AddRange((from item in Hooks
                        where item.category == category
                        select item).ToArray());
```

I don't think it should matter, but it could be the AddRange method is failing because it's being passed IQueryable when it is expecting IEnumerable

Given my last Comment, here's what I meant:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberofhooks; i++)
{
    Hooks[i] = new Hook(result.Tables[1].Rows[i]);
    if(relevantHookCategories.Contains(Hooks[i].category)
        RelevantHooks.Add(Hook[i]);
}
```

Comment: `Hooks` is an array.  So it shouldn't be an `IQueryable`.  But even if it is `IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I know IQueryable extends IEnumerable, it's why I said it shouldn't matter.

Another thought is why wait until after you populate Hooks to add to RelevantHooks? A simple if statement when you populate Hooks[i] could populate the list and save the need for an extra query.